# NameError: name 'sense2vec_instance' is not defined

Tags: python, nltk, absolute-path

after I ran my model "NameError: name 'sense2vec_instance' is not defined" this error appeared.

In this model, I was expected to generate questions after uploading a pdf. while trying to fix the error I should define the actual path to my Sense2Vec model.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.